# What is this dial with 3-4 outputs that fits on a breadboard called?

Tags: breadboard

I saw this new 'toy' called the *Fidget Cube*, but one certain side interests me:
[image]

It seems to be a small dial which can spin 360* without much friction  / resistance. 
If I wanted to buy one of these types of components, which may be able to fit on a breadboard (It doesn't have to, just somewhat smaller) which has a common anode or cathode, and can have outputs depending on the degree the dial is rotated to, what would I search for/ask for? Thanks!

Comment: Rotary encoder maybe?

Answer (score 5):

It's a rotary encoder with a custom knob. The output is typically pulses A/B in quadrature that need to go to microcontroller for processing.

[image]

For example, [this](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Electronic%20Components/EVQV5.pdf) Panasonic EVQV5 model which has a detent strength of 9-18mN-m. Some have an integral push switch or LED.